# Adding Different Calendar Views to One Page

Tags: list-view, calendar, connected-web-parts

I want to add a calendar that can simply be done by adding a Calendar App.  However, the issue I having is adding another calendar view to the same Calendar App page.  For instance, if the user adds event to the calendar … the event will appear in the other calendar view as well as the original calendar.  Does anyone know how I can add another calendar to a calendar app page?  Also, connect the two calendars together, therefore, what appears in one can show in the other.

What I was thinking to do is add a Calendar App page and add a calendar web part to the page.  Then change the view for one of the calendars.  However, I am not sure how to connect the two.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much for your help!

See the image below for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add the same App Part for the same Calendar to the page. I think what you're doing is adding a new calendar app, then adding that new calendar to the page? If you add the same Calendar app part from the picker twice, and just change the view in the second app part, you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Excellent, please mark this as answered so the rest of the community can benefit ;)